# Replace quotes by double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I search a Regex or an other way to replace quotes by double quotes. But i would like to keep quote in word. By example keep quote in `jusqu'à`.
I try to find a regular expression but i didn't find.

INPUT:

```
{'nom': 'mulot', 'code': 'apodemus agrarius', 'descriptif': 'mammifère', 4'reconnaissance': "Petit mammifère rongeur sauteur jusqu'à 80 cm et nageur.", 'conditions': ' ', 'sources': ' '}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"nom": "mulot", "code": "apodemus agrarius", "descriptif": "mammifère", "reconnaissance": "Petit mammifère rongeur sauteur jusqu'à 80 cm et nageur.", "conditions": ' ', "sources": " "}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'nom': 'mulot', 'code': 'apodemus agrarius', 'descriptif': 'mammifre', 'reconnaissance': "Petit mammif're rongeur sauteur jusqu's 80 cm et nageur.", 'conditions': ' ', 'sources': ' '}))

Comment: Is the input a `string` or an `object`?

Comment: is input string and i would like to be a output dictionary object.

Comment: you have a typo in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you would need to split on commas, loop over that, split on colons, loop over that, replace the quotes, join that back together, and than join the first split back together.

```js
var str = "{'nom': 'mulot', 'code': 'apodemus agrarius', 'descriptif': 'mammifère', 'reconnaissance': \"Petit mammifère rongeur sauteur jusqu'à 80 cm et nageur.\", 'conditions': ' ', 'sources': ' '}";

var rep = "{" + str.substr(1, str.length - 2).split(/\s?,\s?/).map(function(v) {
  return v.split(/\s?:\s?/).map(function(p) {
    return p.replace(/^\s?'([^']+)'\s?$/, '"$1"');
  }).join(":");
}).join(",") + "}";


console.log(rep);
```

Problems with this"

1. it does not check for `"` inside of the string. Will cause issue.
2. If string contains a `,` it will break
3. If the string contains `:` it will break
4. Does not handle arrays/objects inside

Another solution (which is not 100% safe) is eval() or new Function()

```js
var str = "{'nom': 'mulot', 'code': 'apodemus agrarius', 'descriptif': 'mammifère','reconnaissance': \"Petit mammifère rongeur sauteur jusqu'à 80 cm et nageur.\", 'conditions': ' ', 'sources': ' '}";

var arr = new Function("return " + str)();
console.log(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Now the best solution, fix whatever is outputting/inputting it in the first place.